# can't setState on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm running into an issue I'm hoping someone can help explain what this error is appearing. When a componentDidMount I always set isMounted to true and false when componentWillUnmount. Now I'm a bit confused because in the image attached, I put console.logs all over to see what is running what. In the image, you can see the component has true for mounted but fails.[Shows console.logs and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU8UV.png)

When I open the error there are two places where it says it's failing. The first one is

```
 gameStarted() {
    let gameID = this.props.match.params.id;
    let db = firebase.database();
    db.ref(`Room/${gameID}`).on("value", snapshot => {
      let collection = snapshot.val();
      if (collection === null) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        collection["gameStarted"] === null ||
        collection["gameStarted"] === undefined
      ) {
        return;
      }
      let startGame = collection["gameStarted"];
      console.log("before crash");
      if (this.state.isMounted) {
        console.log("before crash", this.state.isMounted);
        this.setState(
          {
            startGame
          },
          () => {
            console.log("Start Game Worked");
          }
        );
      }
      console.log("after crash");
    });
  }
```

From the image above we can see the console.log("before crash", true) being run before the error appears. I'm a bit confused in this aspect since it should work since the local state is set to true? no?

Next error to appear is within a different component. The way it's set up is, if a user to not part of the waiting room, they get redirected to join room component. This is where the second error appears as

```
   const loginPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          window.user = user;
          resolve(user.uid);
        } else {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .signInAnonymously()
            .then(user => {
              resolve(user.uid);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        }
      });
    });
    loginPromise.then(id => {
      console.log("before crash", this.state.isMounted);
      let db = firebase.database();
      let playersRef = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/players`);
      playersRef.child(`${id}`).set(`${this.state.username}`);
      console.log("After crash", this.state.isMounted);
      let player = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/players/${id}`);
      player.onDisconnect().remove();

      let allPlayers = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/all-players`);
      allPlayers.child(`${id}`).set(true);
      let allPlayer = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/all-players/${id}`);
      allPlayer.onDisconnect().remove();

      let scoreBoard = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/scoreBoard`);
      scoreBoard.child(`${this.state.username}`).set(0);
      let playerScore = db.ref(
        `Room/${this.state.accesscode}/scoreBoard/${this.state.username}`
      );
      playerScore.onDisconnect().remove();

      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: `/waiting-room/${this.state.accesscode}`
      });
    });
  }
```

Although I don't think this part is the case since within console it still continues on without crashing. So when a user set the waiting room url, if they aren't part of the room they'll be redirected to a join-room component where they'll need to input a username before going back to the game-room compnent. I understand these redirects could be the issue, any advice on how I can solve this setState in regards to unmounting a component?

[UPDATE]
Could it be because the promise is still running in the join-room component which is why it's failing once it heads to the waiting-room component? This basically only appear once the createUser is fire from join-room button

Thank you for all the help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop subscription events before unmount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    let gameID = this.props.match.params.id;
    let db = firebase.database();
    db.ref(`Room/${gameID}`).off("value");
}
```

Your component will stop receiving update events and state will not be updated

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue I was having and great to learn something new :)